# Why dont we add 'ngModule' in decorator array of app.module.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, decorator, ng-modules

I am making an angular project and have made required components and imported modules too. The main issue I see here ... is that we make 2 steps:

1. **Add component, services, pipes, modules to the top** adding respective files or folder locations
2. **Add them in decorator** (components, pipes, models go to declarations), (Modules to  imports) and (services to providers).

There is an exception. Now, I expected that just like '**browser-module**' (pre-fetched) or 'forms-module' (added manually) -- in the step-2 (ie, decorator array) there should be an injection or name-addition for '**ng-Module**'. Why is it not there? Is this only exception or there is some other too? Shouldn't 'ngModule' be added in decorator would have been a consistent way?

[image]

> **Note:** Code is not required as app it is working fine. The question is simple that if we are using a particular rule for all --
>   Components, Services, Modules, Pipes, Models and Interface -- why not
>   for 'ngModule'?

Comment: please add code not images

Comment: Sir, code is not required for this case, its a simple reasoning of not adding item to a particular array.

Answer (score 1):

NgModule is a class marked by the @NgModule decorator. It is not a separate Module that is configured in your application.

Comment: meaning ... ngModule is different than all the other modules?

Comment: ngModule comes with Angualr core. Its an decorator that you use to declare your modules.

Comment: But, so does 'browserModule' ... isn't it ... and we have to use it to run even a single page. Then why is it added in 'imports' array (part of bottom declaration of step 2)?

Comment: https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/understanding-angular-modules-ngmodule-and-their-scopes-81e4ed6f7407

Answer (score 1):

It is required because you use `@NgModule` decorator at definition of your module. It's just a decorator and not a module. You need to import its script because you simply use it. You can think of it as `@Input` or `@Output` decorators. You import them within your components just to use it within component.

You can look at the [code of `NgModule`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/metadata/ng_module.ts)

It is an interface

`export interface NgModule { ...`

However, `BrowserModule` is a module that decorates itself with `@NgModule`

Check the [code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-browser/src/browser.ts)

```
@NgModule({providers: BROWSER_MODULE_PROVIDERS, exports: [CommonModule, ApplicationModule]})
export class BrowserModule { ...
```

Comment: Then, why do we import 'browserModule' which is also part of 'angular/core' as asked by @sajeetharan also. Rules must be same for both. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, I meant the latter. It's not a module, just a decorator. `BrowserModule` is a module that provides bunch of stuff

Answer (score 1):

AOT Complier contains 2 phases.

1. Code Analysis Phase
   2) Code Generation Phase

During Code Analysis Phase, with the help @ngModule class decorator AOT Compiler will get the metadata about the module. Using these details, it will create metadata.json for Compilation.

During Code Generation Phase, it will create module factories.